# Is it possible to determine if HTML5 permissions have been granted previously? (full screen / pointer lock e.t.c.)

Tags: javascript, html

Background: 
I'm writing a browser based drawing capture program in which I use the pointer lock API to capture the cursor in a canvas. 
However the first time a user clicks the canvas they get a pop up from the browser requesting permission, resulting in unwanted behaviour until they have accepted and refreshed the page, thereafter everything is fine.

Question:
I would like to test if the user has already given pointer lock permission to the domain before even displaying the canvas (if they have not granted permission I can then request this in a controlled manner before they get to drawing anything).

Any help would be useful, I cannot see it in the specs e.t.c. so it might need to be a more creative solution.

Regards.

Comment: What browser displays the error? Or are you seeing the same behaviour in all?

Comment: I'm not getting an error from the browser, just that moving up to click the allow button to grant permission for the cursor lock event ends up with the locked cursor and the real cursor being out of alignment somewhat, and with lines being drawn to the permission bubble for example. 

Id like to be able to just not show the canvas unless permission has already been granted (maybe by a button elsewhere on the page)